# Is PostgreSQL smart enough to avoid re-running constant join expressions for each row?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, query-optimization

Is Postgres smart enough to not re-run joins or subselects for every result row, if the join or subselect does not depend upon anything else in the row?

For example:

In Postgres, I have two tables, `account` and `profile`. I want to write a query that returns all profiles of users who are active, and they should only be returned if the calling user (whose `user_id` is provided in the variable `$userId`) is also active. In SQL, this would be:

```
select * from profile
left outer join account as viewer_account on
  viewer_account.user_id = $userId
left outer join account as profile_account on
  profile_account.user_id = profile.user_id
where 
  viewer_account.account_status = 'active' and
  profile_account.account_status = 'active'
```

The question I have is that `viewer_account` will be the same in every row -- it doesn't depend upon the `profile` result (specifically, it does not depend upon `profile.user_id`, like `profile_account` does). But is that first outer join performed for every row (wasting work), or is it performed just once, and then copied into each row of the result set?

Comment: I would also expect Postgresql to realize regular inner joins are performed here.

Comment: @RichardHuxton because I'm brand new to Postgres and have no idea how to even use that (but I'll go look it up). Have a little compassion for n00bs, please?

Comment: In which case don't worry about the finer details of performance tuning, concentrate instead on e.g. the difference between an inner join and an outer join like @jarlh points out.

Comment: @RichardHuxton I asked the question because I need to care about performance and scalability for this application, and your comments are not helping.

Comment: @jarlh in the actual application, I use `is not distinct from 'active'`, rather than `= 'active'`, which I think makes it impossible for Postgres to automatically convert this into an inner join.

Comment: Let the database tell you: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/using-explain.html In reality you always need something like `explain(analyze, verbose, buffers)` for your SQL statements. Just explain tells you almost nothing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually, the PostgreSQL query planner is intelligent enough to identify scenarios in which a portion of the query may be computed only once for the full result set and doesn't depend on the rows being processed. By computing the result of the initial join only once and reusing it, it might optimize the execution plan appropriately. Check the EXPLAIN output for the particular execution plan that the planner selected.

```
EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM profile
LEFT OUTER JOIN account AS viewer_account ON viewer_account.user_id = $userId
LEFT OUTER JOIN account AS profile_account ON profile_account.user_id = profile.user_id
WHERE viewer_account.account_status = 'active' AND profile_account.account_status = 'active';
```

Hope it's helpful:)

Comment: Thanks! It looks like the index scan on `viewer_account` is hoisted out of the hash join between `profile_account` and `profile`, and run as a separate operation, so yes, this looks like it is going to work optimally.